# External URL link retrieved from database TWIG,Drupal 8

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I'm using Drupal 8. I'm trying to create a hyperlink to an external URL, which is retrieved from a database.

My code works when I put `<a href ="{{ webform_submission_value_18.0.url }}">{{ webform_submission_value_18 }} </a>`.

but when I put `<a href ="{{ webform_submission_value_18.0.url }}">Regestration</a>`
doesn't work, because in the first case the link is token from {{ webform_submission_value_18 }}. I tried also `content.webform_submission_value_18.0['#url']` but It doesn't work.
Can you help me please?

Comment: Unclear, there is no reason why snippet 1 should work and snippet 2 does not

Comment: actually, the first one works, because it takes the link directly from the title not from href.

Comment: In your example both hrefs are made from the `url` property: `<a href ="{{ webform_submission_value_18.0.url }}">{{ webform_submission_value_18 }} </a>` and `a href ="{{ webform_submission_value_18.0.url }}">Regestration</a>`. You prolly have copy/pasted the wrong code then?

Comment: For that, I think url property don't work.

Comment: `the first one works, because it takes the link directly from the title not from href` you mean some JS does this? Because in snippet 1 you're using `webform_submission_value_18` as an array, and then as a string. There must be something wrong there. It is either an array or a string, which in your case seems to be the latter.

Comment: I didn't add any JS code, It's work by itself the snippet 1, but the snippet 2 I couldn't find a solution to solve it